Embed CSS file when org-exporting
I have a custom css file I include when exporting org files to HTML, by linking to it in the head section, like so:
(setq org-html-head "<!-- Site css -->
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/home/user/.emacs.d/org-publishing/site.css\"/>")

I'm trying to make the file more portable by directly embedding the css, so that it's like a 1-file HTML page. Something like this:
(setq org-html-head (concat "<!-- Site css-->
<style type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\">" (insert-file-contents "/home/user/.emacs.d/org-publishing/site.css") "</style>"))

However this is not quite working how I expect. I'm trying to embed all the CSS contents in the site.css file directly into the HTML files when exporting. What's the correct way to do this?

(setq org-html-head
      (concat "<!-- Site css-->
      <style type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\">"
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert-file-contents "/home/user/.emacs.d/org-publishing/site.css")
        (buffer-string))
      "</style>"))

I'm not sure this exact code will work because of copy/paste/reformat/etc, but the key code is:
(with-temp-buffer
   (insert-file-contents "/home/user/.emacs.d/org-publishing/site.css")
   (buffer-string))

Which will return a string object that concat will be happy with.
